# Visual C++: Invalid allocation size. How to force the debugger to stop on this message?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, debugging, memory-management

The MFC program I am debugging is printing this message in the "Output" window in Visual Studio 9.0:

```
HEAP[AppName.exe]: Invalid allocation size - 99999998 (exceeded 7ffdefff)
```

I'm pretty sure this is due to a bad "new", uninitialized variable or similar error.

The question is: how do I get the debugger to stop on this message so that I can view the stack trace and solve the problem?

---

Edit: The following snippets do not yield the same warning. They produce the `Invalid allocation size: 4294967295 bytes.` style message instead.

```
int stupid = -1;
char *bob = new char[stupid];
```

And:

```
malloc(-1);
```

So, I suspect it's coming from within a system DLL with its own memory management or is using a different API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is probably coming from `HeapAlloc()` in ntdll.dll.

I can reproduce the message with the following code:

```
HANDLE hHeap = HeapCreate(0, 0, 4096);
LPVOID p = HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, 0x99999998);
```

The message gets sent to the debugger output window by `DbgPrint()` in ntdll.dll, so I would try setting a breakpoint there (it's an exported function, so you won't need a symbol file to find its address) and then looking at your call stack.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it to break there. I've tried various combination of `{,,ntdll.dll}_DbgPrint@4`. Any ideas?

Comment: One method is to use `dumpbin` on ntdll.dll to find the image base and offset of `DbgPrint()`, add the two together to find the function's virtual address, then create a breakpoint at that address (which can only be done once your process is running - so you'll need to step in, then set the breakpoint, then continue).

Comment: I set the language to `Unknown` and the function to `{,,ntdll.dll}_DbgPrint` to get the breakpoint to work. Got it! A `CListCtrl::GetColumn` call that was leading to the heap message.

Answer (score 1):

That error message is printed at line 409 of dbgheap.c which is in Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src.  You should be able to just set a breakpoint there.

Comment: That's not the same message: `_RPT1(_CRT_ERROR, "Invalid allocation size: %Iu bytes.\n", nSize);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the menu bar, go to `Debug -> Exceptions`. Add a `C++-Exception` called `std::bad_alloc` and check the checkbox `Thrown` to stop where the exception was thrown.

Comment: This idea didn't get the debugger's attention. Is there a way I can break on the function that sends the warning string to the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where that function is, or what it's called? Grep the runtime sources for the strings in the error message. Try setting a breakpoint on function call or file/location, in the Debug->New breakpoint dialog.

If that doesn't work, you can break out the big gun (but this is painful and time-consuming) and modify the file where the function is implemented (if it's in a header - if it's in a .cpp file it's even more work). Add this:

```
__asm {
    int 3;
}
```

to manually insert a 'break into debugger' opcode. This is a trick I often use to force a breakpoint in a dll for which the debugger fails to identify a location for a breakpoint correctly.